# where can I found the file in the host machine when installed it using `adb push /data/hello.apk` on simulator

Tags: android

I am assuming that , in the host machine , i can find a file calling `$(PREFIX)/data/hello.apk`. But I did not find it , either in `android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8/data` nor in `~/.android/avd/myAvd`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do an `adb push`, you're putting data inside of the on-device disk storage. This is in fact stocked **into** the emulator, as it would be stocked in the internal disk in a real phone. Why do you want to retrieve this file ?

Comment: I want to make sure the application has really get updated by checking the date for instance.

Comment: It seems I could achieve my goal my using `adb shell` and `ls -l app/com.example.hello.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html